# Submit to a specific button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I got a userscript that checks for a regex and replaces it if it appears. It's for a MyBB forum, so when I post a thread there are 2 button:

Post Reply | Preview Post

If I press Post Reply, the script won't work, but if I press on Preview Post, the regex will get replaced.

Here's the code:
http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/161320

Can anyone tell me how I can make it replace when I press on Post Reply instead of Preview Post? Or both would be awesome.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `form._submit();` you want to find the button and call its `click()` method.

In jquery it would look like:

```
$("#id_of_button").click();
```

Comment: It didn't work. I replaced the #id_of_button to the ID of the button and it won't even submit now.

Comment: Where does your userscript run? In a plugin inside of Firefox?